# Set file encoding

Tags: character-encoding, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently struggeling with following issue.

- Developing in Lua
- Different file encoding per file extension *(for instance: "*.lua" -> iso88591, "*.lu8" -> utf8)*

Actually there is no way to solve this in the `settings.json` (only per language).
So I decided to develop an extension setting the charset per file name (custom setting `charset.assignment`).

**settings.json**

```js
...
"files.associations": {
  "*.lu8": "lua"
},
"[lua]": {
  "files.encoding": "utf8"
},
"charset.assignment": {
  "*.lua": "iso88591"
},
...
```

So now I "only" have to set the character set of the current file in my `extension.ts`, but I didn't find any opportunity to do this. At the moment I'm trying to execute the workbench command `workbench.action.editor.changeEncoding`, it shows up, but I still have to manually chose the character set.
Anyone knows, if it's possible to refer some parameters to the command (like `vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.editor.changeEncoding', 'iso88591');`?

**Similar question (but for getting the current charset):**

- [VSCode: activeTextEditor encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524800/vscode-activetexteditor-encoding)

**Links:**

- [Provide encoding-related APIs for editor extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/824)
- [add support for `charset`](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode/issues/35)
- [ChangeEncodingAction](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/browser/parts/editor/editorStatus.ts#L1235)
- [File extension specific settings](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35350)

Comment: It doesn't look like the `ChangeEncodingAction` command was designed to be called programatically / accepts any parameters.

Comment: That's sad, so I really have to wait for an extension of the api. Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You could try implementing that yourself in a pull request... though you should probably discuss that first in an issue with the VSCode devs, to avoid unnecessary work in case it's not even a feature they want.